# Perl script to convert xls to csv

Tags: perl, csv, xls

This script coverts xls to csv ok.
The challenge is that it does not convert blank cell in the xls to blanks in csv file.
Any help is appreciated: **UPDATED SCRIPT**

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;
use Text::CSV;

my $sourcename = shift @ARGV or die "invocation: $0 <source file>\n";
my $source_excel = new Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;
my $source_book = $source_excel->Parse($sourcename)
    or die "Could not open source Excel file $sourcename: $!";
my $storage_book;

foreach my $source_sheet_number (0 .. $source_book->{SheetCount}-1) {
 my $source_sheet = $source_book->{Worksheet}[$source_sheet_number];

 print "--------- SHEET:", $source_sheet->{Name}, "\n";
 next unless defined $source_sheet->{MaxRow};
 next unless $source_sheet->{MinRow} <= $source_sheet->{MaxRow};
 next unless defined $source_sheet->{MaxCol};
 next unless $source_sheet->{MinCol} <= $source_sheet->{MaxCol};

 foreach my $row_index ($source_sheet->{MinRow} .. $source_sheet->{MaxRow}) {
  foreach my $col_index ($source_sheet->{MinCol} .. $source_sheet->{MaxCol}) {
   my $source_cell = $source_sheet->{Cells}[$row_index][$col_index];
   if ($source_cell && $source_cell->Value) {
   #print "( $row_index , $col_index ) =>", $source_cell->Value, "\t;";
   print  $source_cell->Value, ";";
   }
 else
  {
  print ";"
   }
  }
 }
}
```

sample excel

```
EFG KDD ABS JME
FGO     POP JET
```

converted as:

```
EFG;KDD;ABS;JME;
FGO;POP;JET;
```

but it should be:

```
EFG;KDD;ABS;JME;
FGO;;POP;JET;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check if the value of the cell is initialized, not the cell it self.

Change:

```
   if ($source_cell) {
      #print "( $row_index , $col_index ) =>", $source_cell->Value, "\t;";
       print  $source_cell->Value, ";";
   }
```

To:

```
   if ($source_cell && $source_cell->Value) {
      #print "( $row_index , $col_index ) =>", $source_cell->Value, "\t;";
      print  $source_cell->Value, ";";
   } else {
      print  ";";
   }
```

should work.

UPDATE:

```
 foreach my $row_index ($source_sheet->{MinRow} .. $source_sheet->{MaxRow}) {
  foreach my $col_index ($source_sheet->{MinCol} .. $source_sheet->{MaxCol}) {
   my $source_cell = $source_sheet->{Cells}[$row_index][$col_index];
   if ($source_cell && $source_cell->Value) {
      print  $source_cell->Value.";";
   } else {
      print ";";
   }
  }
  print "\n";
 }
}
```

Comment: but I got below error: `Can't call method "Value" on an undefined value at  line 23`

Comment: If `$source_cell` is undef, then `Value` will error. You might find:
`if ( defined $source_cell and defined $source_cell -> Value ) {` does better.

Comment: @Jens. Thanks. I just updated the script with your new answer but the result still ignore the blanks in the csv file.

Comment: @Jens. That seems to work.The blanks are included. But it does not print the result(rows in xls) line by line in the csv.

Comment: @Jens. I am using AIX. if I use `print "\n";` it breaks each line at the points where blank columns exist.

Comment: @Jens. It should be FGO;;POP;JET;  instead it breaks the line into 2. At end of FGO;  and second line start with POP;JET;

Comment: @Drsin looks craz. Can you update the question with the code you know have?

Comment: `if ($source_cell && $source_cell->Value) {
   #print "( $row_index , $col_index ) =>", $source_cell->Value, "\t;";
   print  $source_cell->Value, ";";
   }
 else
  {
  print "\n";
   }
`

Comment: @Jens. `else { print ";"}` works. But it converts entire 208 rows in the xls to a single line in the csv file. I need it to return individual lines in the xls back to each rows in the csv file. so `cat aps.csv | wc -l ` returns 1 instead of 208 lines in my xls. hope u understand. And thanks a lot so far.

Comment: @Jens. Thanks a million. It worked perfectly. A beer on me anytime you are Zurich, Switzerland. Thanks.